# Making Maven Surefire to log stack trace in Console and File

Tags: maven, logging, maven-surefire-plugin

Is it possible to configure Surefire to log the stack trace in both, Console and File. By default everything is logged in Console. Using this parameter `redirectTestOutputToFile=true`, the log is redirected to the '-output.txt' file under target/surefire-reports.

I need to log to Console and File at the same time, is that possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Configure you logging framework accordingly.